# Query Knowledge Article Type Query - if language is not always known ahead of time

Tags: soql, knowledge

I have custom vf page which loads some fields from knowledge article type, this page currently contains hard coded language filter in soql query which limits from loading any other non English content.

I may not know the knowledge article language ahead of time while loading always, just wondering what options to retrieve an article if i know only title, urlname, status?

also I'm not able to include multiple languages in soql query language where clause as well.

sample soql query below, my actual query is similar to this one and contains one additional where clause which is urlname

```
String qryString = 'SELECT Id, title, UrlName, LastPublishedDate,LastModifiedById '+
                   'FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion '+
                   'WHERE (PublishStatus = \'online\' and Language = \'en_US\')';
List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articleList= Database.query(qryString);
```

Thanks

Comment: hey @realnumber you need to get multiple language KnowledgeArticleVersion  records?

Comment: @Ratan I need retireve actually kav article type objects, like faq__kav, etc.